# Remove whitespace from all data in column - Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, whitespace, trim

There is pre filled data in database. In one of the column (Article) in a table (Subsession), there is whitespace at the end. How to remove that via query ?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove white space from the right end then the query would be:

```
UPDATE Subsession SET Article=RTrim(Article)
```

if from both ends then use the Trim function.